# Possible Combination that could be made with the same number

Tags: c, numbers

I'm currently working on a C program that will calculate the number of possibilities that could be made with the same number. For example: 444 should produce 6 number of possibilities (it counts as 4,4,4,44,44,444). I currently think to use a for loop with if statement in it to solve the problem. Thank you

Comment: Define which numbers are considered to be possibility of given number. And provide a better example with sufficient explanation.

Comment: it is not clear for me what you call number of possibilites. would 123 produce 1, 2, 3, 12, 23, 123?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you are asking, but if I understand correctly there is a very simple formula for that

Given a number of n caracteres, you will have:

- 1 subset of size n
- 2 subsets of size n-1
- ...
- n subset of size 1

So you re computing the sum of i for i in 1..n which is

```
n*(n+1)/2
```

In your exemple 444 is of size 3, and 3*(3+1)/2 = 6